# Why doesn't my restricted Content Hub script have a ChangeTracker?

Tags: content-hub, content-hub-scripting

I have a restricted action script that looks to see if a specific property has changed and stores the new value in the `PropertyBag`. It's based on [this example in the documentation](https://docs.stylelabs.com/content/3.1.x/integrations/scripting-api/scripting-examples/action-script-audit-example.html?q=changetracker).

```
using System.Linq;

var targetItem = Context.Target as IEntity ?? await MClient.Entities.GetAsync(Context.TargetId.Value);

if (targetItem == null) {
    MClient.Logger.Error($"Unable to get asset for Context.TargetId: {Context.TargetId} (Context.TargetType: {Context.TargetType})");
    return;
}

if (Context.ChangeTracker == null) 
{
    MClient.Logger.Error("Context.ChangeTracker is null");
    return;
}

var titleOriginal = Context.ChangeTracker.GetOriginalPropertyValue<string>("Title");
var titleCurrent = await targetItem.GetPropertyValueAsync<string>("Title");

if (titleOriginal.Equals(titleCurrent))
{
    MClient.Logger.Info($"The title of asset {targetItem.Id} was not changed: {titleOriginal}");
}
else
{
    MClient.Logger.Info($"The title of asset {targetItem.Id} was changed from \"{titleOriginal}\" to \"{titleCurrent}\"");

    Context.PropertyBag.Add($"{targetItem.Id}_title", titleCurrent);
}
```

However, when it runs, the `Context.ChangeTracker` is always null:

[image: log entries]

Anyone have any ideas why the `ChangeTracker` would never be set?

Things I've tried:

1. Verifying the script is restricted and the trigger is set to run in process
2. Making a change to multiple properties (including the one I care about) to see if different properties would result in the `ChangeTracker` being hydrated

> Content Hub version: 3.1.3

Answer (score 2):

ChangeTracker is only avaiable on InProcess scripts that are fired on Pre-Commit phase.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little late on this one, but can you check your trigger action and ensure it's not running the script in "Post Action".